# How to set JSON result to 'src' of 'img' to show an image in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I’ve got an absolute path of image in JSON format by AJAX at my view. It looks like:

```
var addresIMG=data.result.sourcefile;//address is 'D:/jqueryfileuploadmvc4/MVC4Appl/App_Data/1.png'
```

However, the view cannot render the image as an attribute “src” image should look like:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/App_Data /" + "1.png")"  />
```

But my src of view is:
 // it is not correct as address of image should address to the server

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/Home/UploadFiles',
        autoUpload: true,
        done: function (e, data) {  
             var addresIMG=data.result.sourcefile;//address is 'D:/jqueryfileuploadmvc4/MVC4Appl/App_Data/1.png''
            $(".file_source").attr('src', data.result.sourcefile);//it sets an absolute path and it is incorrect. The image iddress should look like src="@Url.Content("~/App_Data /" + "1.png")" 


        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
    });
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to assign 'src' attribute by result of JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON data should include a relative or absolute URL, not a filesystem path. The browser doesn't have access to the server's filesystem directly, so the src attribute has to use a URL.

The server has to generate the correct URL by mapping the filesystem path like so:

```
var imageUrl = Url.Content("~/App_Data/1.png");
```

The server-side logic that populates your model will have to set the sourcefile property and this will then get serialized and sent to the client as JSON. For example

```
var model = GetModelFromDatabase();  //any code that sets your model object
model.sourcefile = imageUrl;
```

You would then be able to use `var addresIMG=data.result.sourcefile;` without a problem

Comment: so my JSON response should contain: 'Server.MapPath("~/App_Data /1.png")'? I guess my browser cannot recognize such address of source as this JSON response will be assigned in a browser after clicking a button. But I'll try.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. I assume that you are populating your model within an MVC controller action, so you should be able to use Url.Content to get a URL from a path. Server.MapPath obviously does the opposite, so it wouldn't be any help in your case.

Comment: do I understand correctly that model.sourcefile will be address like "'D:/jqueryfileuploadmvc4/MVC4Appl/App_Data/1.png'"?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be like that because a path means nothing to the browser. The browser will expect the src attribute to have a value that is a URL